# PassportJs Google Auth2 failureRedirect not working

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, passport.js, passport-google-oauth

I am using **passport-google-oauth** for authentication of google login. Almost all thing working fine but `failureRedirect` never called when I return error from `config/google.js` file i.e, `return done(new Error('Sorry! Your email id is not found. Please contact to Admin.'));`

explain by example. Please go through below code :-

### config/google.js

```
module.exports = (jwt, app, passport) => {
  const GoogleStrategy = require('passport-google-oauth').OAuth2Strategy;
  const User = require('../../models/user.model');

  passport.use(new GoogleStrategy({
    clientID: "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx",
    clientSecret: "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx",
    callbackURL: "http://localhost:3000/api/user/google/callback"
  },
    function (accessToken, refreshToken, profile, done) {
      User.findOne({
        email: profile.emails[0].value,
        isActive: true
      }, function (err, user) {
        if (err) {
          return done(err);
        }
        if (!user) {
          return done(new Error('Sorry! Your email id is not found. Please contact to Admin.'));
        } else {
          return done(err, user);
        }
      });
    }
  ));
  return passport;
}
```

### server.js

```
........
const passportGoogle = require('./server/config/auth/google')(jwt, app, passport);
const userRoute = require('./server/routes/user.route')(jwt, app, passportGoogle);
..........
```

### user.route.js

```
import express from 'express';
const router = express.Router();
import User from '../models/user.model';
import UserCtrl from '../controllers/user.controller';

module.exports = (jwt, app, passportGoogle) => {
    /* GET api listing. */
    router.get('/', (req, res) => {
        UserCtrl.getUsers({})
            .exec((err, users) => {
                if (err)
                    return next(err);
                res.json(users)
            })
    });

    router.get('/google',
        passportGoogle.authenticate('google', { scope: ['profile', 'email'] }));

    router.get('/google/callback',
        passportGoogle.authenticate('google', { failureRedirect: '/session/login' }),

     //HERE :  failureRedirect: '/session/login' :- it never called

        function (req, res) {
            console.log('req.user', req.user)
            // Successful authentication, redirect home.
            res.redirect('/dashboard');
        });

    return router;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I was just passing by saw your question unanswered, well i think you should send `false` as second parameter instead of user in done callback if you want to reject authentication in a google passport strategy. This shall trigger `failureRedirect`.

```
  function (accessToken, refreshToken, profile, done) {
          User.findOne({
            email: profile.emails[0].value,
            isActive: true
          }, function (err, user) {
            if (err) {
              return done(err);
            }
            if (!user) {
              return done(new Error('Sorry! Your email id is not found. Please contact to Admin.', false));
              // Add False As Second Parameter.
            } else {
              return done(err, user);
            }
          });
        }
      ));
```

Answer (score 0):

the done method should have both parameters as null to trigger the failureRedirect. Like this, done(null, null)